# QTableWidget with setItem cannot access the data in the tablewidget

Tags: c++, qt

void IdListForTrain::SetListIdInList(QStringList IdList)
{

```
QTableWidgetItem *item=nullptr;
for(int index=0;index<IdList.count();index++)
{
    ui->Id_tableWidget->insertRow(index);
    for(qint32 columnIndex=0;columnIndex<=1;columnIndex++)
    {
        item = new QTableWidgetItem;
        if(columnIndex==0)
        {
            ui->Id_tableWidget->setItem(index,columnIndex,item);
            item->setText("00:00:00");
        }
        if(columnIndex==1)
        {
            ui->Id_tableWidget->setItem(index,columnIndex,item);
            item->setText(IdList.at(index));
        }

        QString tmp1 = ui->Id_tableWidget->item(index,1)->text();
        QString tmp = item->text();

    }
}
```

}

Hi! I am new to Qt and I'm facing a problem. I  was asked to create a tablewidget with the effective date of train Ids in one column and the names of the trains in another column,I did this code to the best of my knowledge but I can't set or access the data in the widget in the line eventhough the code doesnt give any errors but it crashes everytime I open the application window at this line,

QString tmp1 = ui->Id_tableWidget->item(index,1)->text();

I'm not sure what the reason is.

Answer (score 1):

Let look at first iteration - `index=0` and `columnIndex=0`.

1. You go through `if(columnIndex==0)` condition and set item to
   QTableWidget's row = 0 (index) and column = 0 (columnIndex)
2. Second condition skipped
3. You try to access item at row = 0 (index) and column = 1 with code `QString tmp1 = ui->Id_tableWidget->item(index,1)->text();`. But at this time you have no item assigned  to that column

That's all!